How can I detect if a column is hidden?
I have a sheet where certain data is hidden and I need to ensure that I don't show that data if it's hidden (which columns are hidden will change frequently).
How can I detect which columns are hidden?

How is it hidden?  Was the width set to 0?  You can fetch the column attributes.

Right-click, hide column. I don't know how to get the width, I haven't found any way to get the column's metadata.

Actually, never mind, I just found it, and a HiddenByUser attribute!

Shortly after asking this question I found the answer by looking around the objects for column metadata. You can get the column metadata from the GridData object within the sheet. It has a few properties like HiddenByFilter, HiddenByUser and PixelSize. This code worked for me but others will need to modify it for their needs, like changing which sheet they're using.
public List<int> GetHiddenColumns(string spreadsheetId, string sheetRange)
{
    List<int> hiddenColumns = new List<int>();

    // Retrieve the sheet properties to determine column visibility
    var sheetRequest = _sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId);
    sheetRequest.Ranges = new[] { sheetRange };
    sheetRequest.IncludeGridData = true;
    var sheetResponse = sheetRequest.Execute();

    if (sheetResponse.Sheets != null && sheetResponse.Sheets.Count > 0)
    {
        var sheetProperties = sheetResponse.Sheets[0];

        var rowData = sheetProperties.Data.FirstOrDefault();

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < rowData.ColumnMetadata.Count; columnIndex++)
        {
            var columnMetadata = rowData.ColumnMetadata[columnIndex];
            if (columnMetadata.HiddenByUser == true) hiddenColumns.Add(columnIndex);
        }
    }

    return hiddenColumns;
}

